# Automatically add Cloudwatch Alarms and Dashboards for new EC2 instances

Tags: aws-lambda, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a Cloudwatch Alarm and Dashboard for the disk space on my EC2 instance. Which is fine until autoscaling spins up a new instance and I have to manually edit the alarm + dashboard with the new instance id.
I suspect the solution lies with setting up Cloudwatch rules for when a new instance starts combined with Lambda although I'd really like some help with the Lambda side of things, if anyone can advise.

```
#Cloudwatch Alarm
    {
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "metrics": [
            [ "CWAgent", "disk_used_percent", "path", "/", "InstanceId", "i-1234567890", "AutoScalingGroupName", "my-autoscalinggrp", "ImageId", "ami-a1b2c3d4e5", "InstanceType", "t3.micro", "device", "nvme0n1p1", "fstype", "xfs", { "stat": "Average" } ]
        ],
        "view": "timeSeries",
        "stacked": false,
        "period": 300,
        "annotations": {
            "horizontal": [
                {
                    "label": "disk_used_percent >= 80 for 1 datapoints within 5 minutes",
                    "value": 80
                }
            ]
        },
        "title": "disk-used-alarm"
    }



#Dashboard
    {
        "metrics": [
            [ "CWAgent", "disk_used_percent", "path", "/", "InstanceId", "i-1234567890", "AutoScalingGroupName", "my-autoscalinggrp", "ImageId", "ami-a1b2c3d4e5", "InstanceType", "t3.small", "device", "nvme0n1p1", "fstype", "xfs", { "label": "Server1" } ]
        ],
        "view": "singleValue",
        "stacked": false,
        "region": "eu-west-1",
        "stat": "Average",
        "period": 300,
        "title": "Disk Usage Dashboard"
    }
```

Comment: It does not make sense to monitor individual instance in the ASG (autoscaling group) because they can come and go. It make sense to monitor the ASG as a whole, and there are metrics available specifically for ASG. If you are monitoring individual instance, you are treating each instance as a pet, not as cattle. Search "cattle vs pet" in your favourite search engine

Comment: thankyou although I am not attached to individual instances per se, but I do still want to receive an alert when an instance disk size is close to full.
Happy to go with monitoring the disk_used_percent for the ASG if that is preferable although I am still unsure how to automate that.

Comment: if you use autoscaling, each instance disk should only store OS or package related files. you should not store files upload from the user into the independent EC2 instance. use EFS to store file that is outside the use of OS or software that you deploy

Comment: it is only storing OS/deployment/cache, still need to monitor the disk used